# Angular UI Router: Errors on page refresh because script paths are being modified

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and define a route like

```
.state('system.personinfo', {
    url: '/persons/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/system/person-info.html',
    data: {
        role: ['admin']
    },
    controller: 'PersonInfoController',
})
```

Works like a charm, but when I'm refreshing the page I get nothing but errors, because all the paths to the scripts now have 'persons/' added at the beginning of the path. So for some reason I don't know the url of the route gets added to all the links.

I'm using HTML5Mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
```

If I don't use the 'ID' parameter page refresh works, so

```
.state('system.personinfo', {
    url: '/persons',
    templateUrl: 'views/system/person-info.html',
    data: {
        role: ['admin']
    },
    controller: 'PersonInfoController',
})
```

actually works.

Can anyone tell what I'm missing here?

Comment: for page refresh to work with `html5Mode`, you need to configure your server to do server side rewrites.   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the missing `<base>` tag in the header. So adding

```
<base href="/">
```

in the header section solved the problem.

From the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase):

> If you configure $location to use html5Mode, you need to specify the base URL for the application with a  tag

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10903570)

Comment: This actually is the answer, I just didn't have enough reputation to answer my own question a few hours after I asked it (guess it is the reputation, there was a warning telling me I needed to wait a day to accept it as an answer).

Comment: @user3255061 if you can answer why your answer worked would be more helpful than just the answer.Pls explain more if you can.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that used to angular yet unfortunately, but I tried (linked the documentation and quoted a section that is the reason if I understood it right). But thanks for your hint to make my answers better, appreciate that.